# Element in chain and antichain

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

When analyzing one poset graph, can an element be both in the longest chain and the longest antichain? 
(or do chains and antichains have to be mutually exclusive?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element could be both in a longest chain and a longest anti-chain.  Consider the boolean lattice (subsets of an $n$-element set).  Any full chain (from the top to the bottom) is a longest chain.  The middle row is a longest anti-chain.  But any full chain will hit an element in the middle row.

Comment: When finding an antichain, do I make sure that none of those subsequent points are connected to each other?

Comment: Yes.  If you are building up an anti-chain, none of the points you select in the future can be connected (contained in, or contain) any of your previous points.  If there are any "comparabilities" it is no longer an anti-chain.